# remote jquery.validator not waiting for response

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use a remote handler to validate that an email the user is submitting is not already used.  This is as part of a wizard using the [formtowizard](https://github.com/artoodetoo/formToWizard) plugin.

However, when i click Next on the wizard it does not wait for the asynchronous response to be returned and goes on to the next step.  However, if i go back and wait for the response then it works fine and I cannot continue.

I have tried to force an sychnronous remote request however this is not working.

So the question is, how to make the remote validation check synchronous ...

NOTE: This is part of a wordpress plugin, hence why I use jQuery instead of $.

```
jQuery('#SignupForm').validate({
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: ajax.ajaxurl,
            async: false
        }
    }
},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    // Show error
},
errorElement: 'em',
submitHandler: function (form) {

// Submit code is here

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.